# Add an default option to a product from product view

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart, custom-options, products-view

I want to give the customers a choice to wrap the order as a gift.

I know that I can add it as a custom option. But every product is wrappable.

I want to show an option for gift wrapping in the product view for every product and when you check it, it will be added to the product as an option in the shopping cart. But I don't want to add the option to every product in the backend.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Without programming? No.

With programming yes. Add the select box to the product page, implement an observer and follow the post by Vinai to save the stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344336/1480397